# How to set up Apache with 3 sites: Two name based virtual hosts and one via the IP address

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have 2 sites linked to domains already.

For this  I have 2 conf files into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`:

```
<domain1>.conf
<domain2>.conf
```

With `DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1` and `DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2`.

In addition, I need to setup the 3rd site direct linked to server IP.

For this I created conf file:
IP.conf (**IP** is IP of the server):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <email>
    ServerName <IP>
    ServerAlias <IP>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Run:

```
sudo a2ensite <IP>.conf
```

And:

```
restart apache service.
```

But it doesn't help.

Could you advise how to configure routing?

Comment: 1st config is: `<VirtualHost *:80> ServerAdmin <email> ServerName <domain1> ServerAlias <domain1> DocumentRoot /var/www/<domain1>/html ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined </VirtualHost>` And it works. Seconf config is similar, but with <domain2>, and it works too.

Comment: The difference in 3rd config is only that in `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` I haven't what to write as haven't registered 3rd domain yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The issue is the default Apache config always uses the IP address of the server. So that `IP.conf` will never be loaded.

### You need to edit the default Apache config — located in `sites-available`  — to make your changes.

Looking at your config, you are indicating the raw IP address for the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` that will — effectively — defeat the purpose of setting up name based virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <email>
    ServerName <IP>
    ServerAlias <IP>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What happens in a case like this is the configs will be ignored because the default Apache setup will always defer to the IP address of the machine you are on. Heck, it would even use all network interfaces if your server has multiple IP addresses.

For name based virtual hosting to work, you *must* use the domain/host name in your config. Something like this for `domain1`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <email>
    ServerName <domain1>
    ServerAlias <domain1>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain1
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And this for `domain2`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <email>
    ServerName <domain2>
    ServerAlias <domain2>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now for the IP address host config, you should go into your Apache config directory — `/etc/apache2/` on Debian/Ubuntu or `/etc/httpd/` on CentOS/RedHat — and look inside the `sites-available` directory. There should be a file named `000-default.conf`:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

And make the changes you are showing in your `IP.conf` in there. At a most basic level just change the `DocumentRoot` to be this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/wordpress
```

Then restart Apache and it should be working as expected.